# Why does FFmpeg choose 10+20+20 ms instead of an even 16 ms for 60 fps GIF images?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, animated-gif

I have a short 60 fps video which I'd like to turn into a GIF file. I run

```
ffmpeg -i foo.flv foo.gif
```

and it produces a GIF file. Great!

The only problem is that the motion in the produced GIF video is janky and uneven. If I use another tool, I can see that FFmpeg has created a video where the first frame is 10 ms long, the second 20 ms, the third 20 ms, and then it repeats like that: 10 ms, 20 ms, 20 ms. If I use another tool to smooth it out to an even 16 ms for each frame (without changing the frame contents), the result looks beautiful.

Why is FFmpeg doing this? How can I ask it to write a GIF file that requests an even 16 ms per frame instead, so that I don't need to use a second tool?

I have now seen this [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/1449366) asking whether 60 fps GIF videos even exist, but it doesn't address the question of how to ask FFmpeg to change its behavior. Additionally, it raises a new question: if 16ms is not a time that GIF can represent, what is the other tool I'm using doing, and why does it work well?

Comment: *but it doesn't address the question of how to ask ffmpeg to change its behavior.* --> that's what my answer in that thread does.

Comment: @Gyan Interesting. I read your answer as describing how to get it to do what it appears to already be doing: getting 60fps by choosing 10ms, 20ms, 20ms. In particular, the chunk of code `if(not(mod(N,3)),PREV_OUTPTS+1,PREV_OUTPTS+2)` looks to me like just what you would want for generating that 1-2-2 pattern. Am I wrong?

Comment: Mine creates a 2-2-1 pattern. If you omit the filter, ffmpeg will make a uniform 2-1-2 pattern if the input is a constant frame-rate input, but it could lead to an irregular pattern in some run of frames if it's not.

Comment: @Gyan Okay. As described in the question, the theoretically optimal pattern turns out to be practically suboptimal (in part, perhaps, because viewers screw things up as described in Ilmari Karonen's comment below); so this question is about getting ffmpeg to produce a gif with a constant framerate, which your answer does not do.

Comment: Of course not, a 60 fps CFR GIF is not possible, since 100/6 seconds cannot be represented precisely. My answer starts, *this is the basic format to emulate a rolling average of 60 fps*

Answer (score 84, accepted):

As discussed at [Do 60 FPS GIF's actually exist? Or is the maximum 50 FPS?](https://superuser.com/questions/1449366/do-60-fps-gifs-actually-exist-or-is-the-maximum-50-fps), the resolution of frame times in GIF is 10ms, so a nice even 16ms per frame is not possible. So the answers to the questions, in order, are:

> Why is ffmpeg doing this?

Because 10+20+20 gets you 60fps on average, and is the most precise approximation with that property that can be represented within the constraints of the GIF format.

> How can I ask it to write a gif that requests an even 16ms per frame instead, so that I don't need to use a second tool?

You can't, because the gif format can't represent that. But I've found that asking it to make a 50fps video -- which *can* be exactly represented in the GIF format -- produces nice smooth results. This can be done with:

```
ffmpeg -i foo.flv -vf fps=50 foo.gif
```

This uses nearest-neighbor temporal interpolation to choose which frame to transfer to the output.

> If 16ms is not a time that gif can represent, what is the other tool I'm using doing, and why does it work well?

The other tool I was using was GIMP, and its choice is to round each frame to the nearest representable size, so it was silently changing my requested 16ms/frame to 20ms/frame. It probably works well because my poor human eyes can't tell that everything was happening just slightly too slowly to be correct; only that motions were happening smoothly instead of at unusually-spaced intervals.

Comment: A word or two about what gif format *can* represent and what the constrains of gif format really *are* would improve this answer.

Comment: Note that, for historical compatibility reasons, [many browsers will treat GIF frame delays of less than 20 ms as if they were 100 ms instead](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/26994) (and some may even do this for any delay less than 60 ms!). So you should never go above 50 fps, and  for maximum compatibility, keep your GIF animations below 100 / 6 = 16.67 fps.

Comment: @Mołot I believe I do have a word or two: "the resolution of frame times in GIF is 10ms". There is also a link to another answer that provides significantly more words explaining this in detail.

Comment: *some sort of temporal interpolation, or whether it simply keeps the same frames in the same order and displays them at the new framerate* --> neither. That filter will drop or duplicate frames while trying to minimize deviation of original display timestamp.

Comment: @Gyan That sounds like nearest-neighbor temporal interpolation to me! Glad to know the precise behavior; I'll update the answer to mention it.

Comment: Interpolation is generating a 'median' value - this is cloning a frame; not the same.

Comment: @Gyan No, that's precisely what nearest-neighbor iterpolation is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation

Comment: I can't find a citation right now, but I do believe browser engines will render a 50 fps GIF as 60 fps, even though it's nonstandard, to match the vertical sync of the monitor.

Comment: Something you may want to add to your answer: If you want to use a different frame interpolation algorithm then you can use the `framerate` (linear) or `minterpolate` (motion compensation, slow) filters. At least with a new enough ffmpeg.