# Does PNG/APNG support 60 FPS animations, or are they limited like GIFs?

Tags: ffmpeg, png, animation, framerate

A similar question like [Do 60 FPS GIF's actually exist? Or is the maximum 50 FPS?](https://superuser.com/questions/1449366/do-60-fps-gifs-actually-exist-or-is-the-maximum-50-fps) but this time for PNG or APNG or any other thing, like WebP.

Is it possible to achieve 60 FPS animations with PNG?

Apperantly, APNG is not the same thing as PNG. It was expanded or applied on the PNG extension as well or not? APNG is older than PNG, right?

Comment: Specifications of file formats are usually published. Any limits of the specification will be available for searching, especially with a well documented and mature and public specification such as PNG or APNG. So, what research have you done prior to asking here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it fails to demonstrate the minimum necessary self-effort on the part of OP.

Comment: https://www.androidpolice.com/2017/05/01/animated-png-format-compare-animated-webp-gif/

Comment: The [APNG spec](https://wiki.mozilla.org/APNG_Specification) contains an example for a time a frame that is displayed `1/100ths of a second` (which would be 100 frames per second if all frames would use that timing).

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, APNG supports 60 fps

The [APNG Specification](https://wiki.mozilla.org/APNG_Specification#.60fcTL.60:_The_Frame_Control_Chunk) says:

> `fcTL`: The Frame Control Chunk
> The `delay_num` and `delay_den`
> parameters together specify a fraction indicating the time to display
> the current frame, in seconds. If the denominator is 0, it is to be
> treated as if it were 100 (that is, `delay_num` then specifies
> 1/100ths of a second). If the the value of the numerator is 0 the
> decoder should render the next frame as quickly as possible, though
> viewers may impose a reasonable lower bound.

So technically APNG can be as fast as the decoder can decode it. Although there may be limits set by various encoder/muxer & decoder/demuxer implementations.

---

### Try it

You can try it yourself by using the [testsrc2 filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#allrgb_002c-allyuv_002c-color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-pal75bars_002c-pal100bars_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc_002c-testsrc2_002c-yuvtestsrc) to generate a sample APNG file:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc2=d=1:r=60 -plays 0 output.apng
```

For more info for the APNG muxer see `ffmpeg -h muxer=apng`.

---

#### Was APNG expanded from the PNG extension?

**Yes.** From the specification:

> APNG is an extension of the PNG format, adding support for animated
> images. It is intended to be a replacement for simple animated images
> that have traditionally used the GIF format, while adding support for
> 24-bit images and 8-bit transparency. APNG is a simpler alternative to
> MNG, providing a spec suitable for the most common usage of animated
> images on the Internet.
>
> APNG is backwards-compatible with PNG; any PNG decoder should be able
> to ignore the APNG-specific chunks and display a single image.

#### APNG is older than PNG, right?

PNG came first and is older than APNG.